# Change value of an attribute with a button in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, button

How would i add a button to my Ruby app that would let me change the value of an attribute, i.e. the value of item.paid from false to true, within a page.

The catch: I want to do this from a different model/view. So for example, in the Customers model, change the value of all 'items' that belong to that customer to paid (with the click of a form button).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`app/controllers/customers_controller.rb`

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController

  def mark_all_items_paid
    customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    customer.items.find_each { |item| item.update_column(:paid, true) }
    # redirect, respond with json, whatever
  end

end
```

`config/routes.rb`

```
resource :customers do
  member do
    post :mark_all_items_paid
  end
end
```

Your view:

```
<%= form_tag { controller: 'customers', action: 'mark_all_items_paid', id: @customer }, { method: :post } do -%>
  <%= submit_tag "Mark All Items Paid" %>
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Closures. Capture those variables in a block, and pass it to the widget to call when it is pressed.